# Get only a part of the line using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a log file and i use awk to extract the required columns. My command is

```
awk '{ print $2" "$5" " $6}' log.txt
```

The $5 column contains the servername and the format can be like @:server1@:@:@:, server2@:@:@:@:@:, @:@:Server3 with no fixed amount of @: symbols.

How do I modify my statement so that I remove all the '@:' from the column 5 to get only the server name?

Comment: You say "$5 column" in one place and "column 3" in another - have we misunderstood where you need to perform the substitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the gensub function.

```
awk '{ print $2, gensub(/@:/, "", "g", $5), $6}' log.txt
```

EDIT: See glenn jackman's comment, below, for possible portability implications.

Comment: Is `gensub()` only in gawk?  `gsub(/@:/, "", $5)` is "portable"

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
awk '{ sub("^(@:)*","",$5); sub("(@:)*$","",$5); print $2" "$5" "$6 }'
```

Note that you can also write `print $2,$5,$6` - the ',' is replaced by the output field separator, which is by default a space.

(edited to remove "@:" from the end of the string as well)